# Lookup value based on multiple columns in data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to figure out how to lookup a value using multiple columns. Just can't seem to get it to work correctly. Here is an example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(g1 = c("a", "b", "c", "c"), g2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
df2 <- data.frame(g.1 = c("a", "b", "c"), g.2 = c(1, 2, 4), val = c(100, 200, 300))
```

So I tried to do:

```
df1$value <- df2[match(df1$g1, df2$g.1) & match(df1$g2, df2$g.2),]$val
```

But this doesn't work for the last value and am guessing it only works for the first 2 just by error. I would like to have df1 look like:

```
  g1 g2 value
1  a  1   100
2  b  2   200
3  c  3    NA
4  c  4   300
```

Comment: Just do a join `setDT(df1)[df2, value := val, on = .(g1, g2)]`

Comment: Also, `match` returns numeric index, so the `&` won't be working as you wanted

Comment: is setDT part of base R? (trying to stay within base R packages if possible but interested in other packages also)

Comment: It is data.table syntax, but if you want base R, then `merge` is better

Comment: Changes in column names can be reflected with `setDT(df1)[df2, value := val, on = .(g1 = g.1, g2 = g.2)]`

Comment: @akrun feel free to add that as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what I am doing wrong based on @G. Grothendieck's answer. All I had to do was:

```
df1$value <- df2[match(paste0(df1$g1,df1$g2), paste0(df2$g.1,df2$g.2)),]$val
```

Answer (score 2):

Try a left join using `merge`:

```
merge(df1, df2, by = 1:2, all.x = TRUE)
```

giving:

```
  g1 g2 val
1  a  1 100
2  b  2 200
3  c  3  NA
4  c  4 300
```

Some alternatives are:

```
transform(df1, val = df2$val[match(paste(g1, g2), paste(df2$g.1, df2$g.2))])

library(sqldf)
sqldf("select df1.*, df2.val 
       from df1 left join df2 on g1 = [g.1] and g2 = [g.2]")

library(dplyr)
df1 %>% left_join(df2, by = c(g1 = "g.1", g2 = "g.2"))
```

Comment: updated the question to show group columns are diferent. So I guess I would need to use "by" with merge.

Answer (score 2):

A join would be better and with `data.table`, it becomes more efficient as we are updating my reference

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, value := val, on = .(g1 = g.1, g2 = g.2)]
df1
#    g1 g2 value
#1:  a  1   100
#2:  b  2   200
#3:  c  3    NA
#4:  c  4   300
```

---

With `match`, one approach would be `paste` the columns of interest together and then create a single index to change the values

```
p1 <- do.call(paste, df1)
p2 <- do.call(paste, df2[1:2])
i1 <- match(p1, p2, nomatch = 0)
i2 <- match(p2, p1, nomatch = 0)
df1$value[i2] <- df2$val[i1]
df1
#  g1 g2 value
#1  a  1   100
#2  b  2   200
#3  c  3    NA
#4  c  4   300
```